# Getting the group_id by using Groups with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, fosuserbundle

I have configured the FOSUserBundle Group follow [Using Groups With FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/groups.md) and get it to work.

```
// src/SM4/UserBundle/Entity/User.php 
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SM4\UserBundle\Entity\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sm4_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
 protected $groups;
```

Every time it creates a new `User`, I can use:

```
$userObj = new \SM4\UserBundle\Entity\User;

$userObj->getId();

$userObj->getEmail();

....

$userObj->getGroup();
```

But how do I get the `Group_id` of user?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function as follow in your `User` entity:

```
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups;
}
```

and another one as follow in your `Group` entity:

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

and that `$this->groups` is an `ArrayCollection` object in your `User` entity, you can do:

```
foreach ($userObj->getGroups() as $group)
{
    //this is where you get your groups id
    echo $group->getId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Me as a follow guide and error occurred "Could not convert database value \"Hello\" to Doctrine Type array"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks cheesemacfly!... one of my ways

**User Entity**

> namespace Hta\CoreBundle\Entity;
>
> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
>
> /**  * HtaUser  */ class HtaUser {
>       /**
>        * @var string
>        */
>       private $username;
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $usernameCanonical;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $email;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $emailCanonical;
>
> /**
>  * @var boolean
>  */
> private $enabled;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $salt;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $password;
>
> /**
>  * @var \DateTime
>  */
> private $lastLogin;
>
> /**
>  * @var boolean
>  */
> private $locked;
>
> /**
>  * @var boolean
>  */
> private $expired;
>
> /**
>  * @var \DateTime
>  */
> private $expiresAt;
>
> /**
>  * @var string
>  */
> private $confirmationToken;
>
> /**
>  * @var \DateTime
>  */
> private $passwordRequestedAt;
>
> /**
>  * @var array
>  */
> private $roles;
>
> /**
>  * @var boolean
>  */
> private $credentialsExpired;
>
> /**
>  * @var \DateTime
>  */
> private $credentialsExpireAt;
>
> /**
>  * @var integer
>  */
> private $id;
>
> /**
>  * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
>  */
> private $group;
>
> /**
>  * Constructor
>  */
> public function __construct()
> {
>     $this->group = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set username
>  *
>  * @param string $username
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setUsername($username)
> {
>     $this->username = $username;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get username
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getUsername()
> {
>     return $this->username;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set usernameCanonical
>  *
>  * @param string $usernameCanonical
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setUsernameCanonical($usernameCanonical)
> {
>     $this->usernameCanonical = $usernameCanonical;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get usernameCanonical
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getUsernameCanonical()
> {
>     return $this->usernameCanonical;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set email
>  *
>  * @param string $email
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setEmail($email)
> {
>     $this->email = $email;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get email
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getEmail()
> {
>     return $this->email;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set emailCanonical
>  *
>  * @param string $emailCanonical
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical)
> {
>     $this->emailCanonical = $emailCanonical;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get emailCanonical
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getEmailCanonical()
> {
>     return $this->emailCanonical;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set enabled
>  *
>  * @param boolean $enabled
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setEnabled($enabled)
> {
>     $this->enabled = $enabled;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get enabled
>  *
>  * @return boolean 
>  */
> public function getEnabled()
> {
>     return $this->enabled;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set salt
>  *
>  * @param string $salt
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setSalt($salt)
> {
>     $this->salt = $salt;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get salt
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getSalt()
> {
>     return $this->salt;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set password
>  *
>  * @param string $password
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setPassword($password)
> {
>     $this->password = $password;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get password
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getPassword()
> {
>     return $this->password;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set lastLogin
>  *
>  * @param \DateTime $lastLogin
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setLastLogin($lastLogin)
> {
>     $this->lastLogin = $lastLogin;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get lastLogin
>  *
>  * @return \DateTime 
>  */
> public function getLastLogin()
> {
>     return $this->lastLogin;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set locked
>  *
>  * @param boolean $locked
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setLocked($locked)
> {
>     $this->locked = $locked;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get locked
>  *
>  * @return boolean 
>  */
> public function getLocked()
> {
>     return $this->locked;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set expired
>  *
>  * @param boolean $expired
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setExpired($expired)
> {
>     $this->expired = $expired;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get expired
>  *
>  * @return boolean 
>  */
> public function getExpired()
> {
>     return $this->expired;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set expiresAt
>  *
>  * @param \DateTime $expiresAt
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setExpiresAt($expiresAt)
> {
>     $this->expiresAt = $expiresAt;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get expiresAt
>  *
>  * @return \DateTime 
>  */
> public function getExpiresAt()
> {
>     return $this->expiresAt;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set confirmationToken
>  *
>  * @param string $confirmationToken
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
> {
>     $this->confirmationToken = $confirmationToken;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get confirmationToken
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getConfirmationToken()
> {
>     return $this->confirmationToken;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set passwordRequestedAt
>  *
>  * @param \DateTime $passwordRequestedAt
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setPasswordRequestedAt($passwordRequestedAt)
> {
>     $this->passwordRequestedAt = $passwordRequestedAt;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get passwordRequestedAt
>  *
>  * @return \DateTime 
>  */
> public function getPasswordRequestedAt()
> {
>     return $this->passwordRequestedAt;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set roles
>  *
>  * @param array $roles
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setRoles($roles)
> {
>     $this->roles = $roles;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get roles
>  *
>  * @return array 
>  */
> public function getRoles()
> {
>     return $this->roles;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set credentialsExpired
>  *
>  * @param boolean $credentialsExpired
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setCredentialsExpired($credentialsExpired)
> {
>     $this->credentialsExpired = $credentialsExpired;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get credentialsExpired
>  *
>  * @return boolean 
>  */
> public function getCredentialsExpired()
> {
>     return $this->credentialsExpired;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set credentialsExpireAt
>  *
>  * @param \DateTime $credentialsExpireAt
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function setCredentialsExpireAt($credentialsExpireAt)
> {
>     $this->credentialsExpireAt = $credentialsExpireAt;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get credentialsExpireAt
>  *
>  * @return \DateTime 
>  */
> public function getCredentialsExpireAt()
> {
>     return $this->credentialsExpireAt;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get id
>  *
>  * @return integer 
>  */
> public function getId()
> {
>     return $this->id;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Add group
>  *
>  * @param \Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaGroup $group
>  * @return HtaUser
>  */
> public function addGroup(\Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaGroup $group)
> {
>     $this->group[] = $group;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Remove group
>  *
>  * @param \Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaGroup $group
>  */
> public function removeGroup(\Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaGroup $group)
> {
>     $this->group->removeElement($group);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get group
>  *
>  * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
>  */
> public function getGroup()
> {
>     return $this->group;
> } }
> ```

Group entity

> namespace Hta\CoreBundle\Entity;
>
> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
>
> /**  * HtaGroup  */ class HtaGroup {
>       /**
>        * @var string
>        */
>       private $name;
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @var array
>  */
> private $roles;
>
> /**
>  * @var integer
>  */
> private $id;
>
> /**
>  * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
>  */
> private $user;
>
> /**
>  * Constructor
>  */
> public function __construct()
> {
>     $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set name
>  *
>  * @param string $name
>  * @return HtaGroup
>  */
> public function setName($name)
> {
>     $this->name = $name;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get name
>  *
>  * @return string 
>  */
> public function getName()
> {
>     return $this->name;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set roles
>  *
>  * @param array $roles
>  * @return HtaGroup
>  */
> public function setRoles($roles)
> {
>     $this->roles = $roles;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get roles
>  *
>  * @return array 
>  */
> public function getRoles()
> {
>     return $this->roles;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get id
>  *
>  * @return integer 
>  */
> public function getId()
> {
>     return $this->id;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Add user
>  *
>  * @param \Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser $user
>  * @return HtaGroup
>  */
> public function addUser(\Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser $user)
> {
>     $this->user[] = $user;
>
>     return $this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Remove user
>  *
>  * @param \Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser $user
>  */
> public function removeUser(\Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser $user)
> {
>     $this->user->removeElement($user);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Get user
>  *
>  * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
>  */
> public function getUser()
> {
>     return $this->user;
> } }
> ```

```
$user = $em -> getRepository('HtaCoreBundle:HtaUser' ) -> find($id);

foreach ($user->getGroup() as $group)
{
    //this is where you get your groups id
    echo $group->getId();
}
```

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 5 bytes in D:\symfony\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType.php line 48

print_r $user object

```
[owner:Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection:private] => Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser Object
        (
        [username:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => admin
        [usernameCanonical:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => admin
        [email:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => admin@yahoo.com
        [emailCanonical:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => admin@yahoo.com
        [enabled:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 1
        [salt:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [password:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [lastLogin:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [locked:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [expired:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [expiresAt:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [confirmationToken:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [passwordRequestedAt:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [roles:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => ROLE_ADMIN
            )

        [credentialsExpired:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [credentialsExpireAt:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 
        [id:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => 2
        [group:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection Object
```

*RECURSION*
        )

how to print joined tables output? ([group:Hta\CoreBundle\Entity\HtaUser:private] => Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection Object
 *RECURSION*
        )

Comment: print group:
echo '<pre>';
print_r(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user->getGroup()));

I war wrong, roles column using DC2Type:array